# What is a good way to transfer data to a DLL?

Tags: dll

Here's my scenario:

I have made a regular DLL in C++ (using VS2008) which provides C interface to exported functions. Two of the concerning functions are *1. initialize() and 2. uninitialize()*

Inside *initialize()* I have to take some parameters from client application. So far, I could think of following two ways to do this:

**First way:**

I make a structure, fill it and pass object/pointer of the structure object to the DLL from client application.

```
    struct SData
    {
        DataType param1;
        DataType param2;
        DataType param3;
        DataType param4;
    };
```

**Second way:**

I export 4 functions from my DLL like

```
    SetParam1(DataType param1)
    SetParam2(DataType param2)
    SetParam3(DataType param3)
    SetParam4(DataType param4)
```

Which way or some other should I use, please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since DLL shares the address space with your application, you can handle it all just by sending a pointer to your struct. If you happen to use different version of the DLL with your application you might also employ some kind of version checking in your function to avoid getting mixed up by different versions of it.

I personally do not recommend `SetParam(param1)` method because it implies a global scope in the DLL thus is not thread-safe. On the other hand passing all parameters to the function itself has a local scope, less prone to bugs, more contained, easier to understand.

For instance you don't know how many functions you need to call before your actual function with the `SetParam` method. But passing parameters in the function allows you to assess if you provide enough parameters just by looking at the function declaration or the struct members. In the case where you need to call individual methods to set parameters, you must have documentation.

Similarly you can put each struct member as a separate parameter in your function but too many parameters become harder to maintain in a single function call after a certain number. Using pointer to a struct in that case is better.

Think yourself as someone who purchased the DLL from a company. How would you prefer the DLL to be? Which way would be easier, more straightforward to write code on?

Comment: Is there a reason you seek for a third way?

Comment: No particular reason. I am just curious if there is another way of doing it other than above two.

Comment: Of course. Countless ways. You can write your parameters to a file and read it from a DLL. Similarly you can open up a pipe, write to it, and read from the pipe in your DLL. Then you can use shared memory to pass the data. These methods though are slower and only used in cases where you need to pass data between processes, rather than a DLL. In DLL case, passing up the pointer is the easiest way. Let me elaborate on the advantages of the methods you mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I read your comment and extended answer and very thankful for your insightful explanation of recommending the structure way. I agree that other methods as you described in your comment are slow. I also implemented structure way initially but thought of looking for other experienced guidelines too and hence I posted the Qn. here. writing and then reading from a file is slow. I didn't understand pipe method. One thing about the structure way. Who has the responsibility of allocating and deallocating memory of the structure?

Comment: It's better if it's client's responsibility. Because DLL has no idea if client wants to reuse the structure or destroy it or not. Second, when DLL and client versions mismatch, DLL might allocate less than what client needs, causing exception. Also allocating structure in client saves you from one additional call to DLL and it's more natural to use your own allocation code rather than calling an ad hoc one.

Comment: Adding to ssg's good advice: A good rule when writing DLLs is that whichever module allocated the memory should also be the one that frees it. Sometimes that means you need to provide a way for one module to ask another to free an object. Doing this ensures you do not run into problems when the objects/sizes change and also when the EXE and DLL(s) do not all use the same heap (which is *very* common when your EXE loads a 3rd party DLL or when your DLL is a plugin to a 3rd party EXE).